# Django Admin. Auto update read_only fields based on other fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

This is my model class:

```
class House(models.Model):
    land_price_per_meter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    land_area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    land_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    build_price_per_meter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    build_area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    build_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    total_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

These fields are read_only :
`land_price` `build_price` `total_price`

I want Django to calculate the read_only fields itself in the admin change_form as the following (real_time):

> `land_price` = `land_price_per_meter` * `land_area`
>
> `build_price` = `build_price_per_meter` * `build_area`
>
> `total_price` = `build_price` + `land_price`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function in
**admin.py**

```
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ("calc_land_price",)

    def calc_land_price(self, instance):
        return land_price_per_meter * land_area

    calc_land_price.short_description = "land_price"
```

But better solution is to create directly in model @property if land_price is just multiplication of two fields, and delete land_price. 
**models.py**

```
class House(models.Model):
    [...]
    @property
    def land_price(self):
        return land_price_per_meter * land_area
```